# How to make a second level of navbar appear from the top of the container?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a second level of navbar appear from the top of the dropdown container, like this:
[What I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo6TB.jpg)

However, I only managed to do it like this(immigrations link hovered), using flexbox:
[What I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BucPH.jpg)

And here is code that I have used:

```css
.nav-more {
  display: flex;
}

.more-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.more-dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-more:hover .more-dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-more">
  <a href="price.html" class="dropdown-link">
    <p>Immigrations<img src="images/arrow-right.svg" class="dropdown-arrow"></p>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-more">
    <div class="more-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>1</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>2</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>3</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>4</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>5</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>6</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear on your question's code if you could send some more HTML and CSS but as far as I understand I think something like this must work

```
<div>//make it flex and direction column

<div> // make it flex and direction row
<div>
<div class="nav-more">
  <a href="price.html" class="dropdown-link">
    <p>Immigrations<img src="images/arrow-right.svg" class="dropdown-arrow"></p>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-more">
    <div class="more-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>1</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>2</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>3</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>4</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>5</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">
        <p>6</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div></div>
```